# nonfree package missing Opencv 3.0 alpha

Tags: opencv

I upgraded my OpenCV library to [3.0 alpha](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-alpha.html) yesterday. I notice that the nonfree package is missing from the source codes. Can someone check to confirm this?

Comment: see [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/40510/30-alpha-missing-nonfree-package/), please.

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem.  I manage to compile the opencv_contrib along with the opencv according to berak's intruction. Thank you very much!