# Nonfree module is missing in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I have built the openCV 3.0 alpha version from source with support for CUDA and TBB. Now, I want to do feature detection and feature matching using SURF algorithm. SurfFeatureDetector is present in the include file

> opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp & opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp

But the module nonfree is missing in this version of openCV. I tried checking the opencv forums at answers.opencv.org but the site is under construction.

How to use the non free modules?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549602/nonfree-package-missing-opencv-3-0-alpha (though with their page being down it won't help much - maybe those people can explain what they did?)

Comment: afaik non_free module has to be chosen explicitly during building. So if you used CMake, there might be a flag you missed?

Comment: @GregorPetrin- So what should I do? Do you happen to read the solution at [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/40510/30-alpha-missing-nonfree-package/)

Comment: @Micka- I used the Cmake-gui. Where in the Cmake gui should I explicitly  choose the non free module? Thanks.

Comment: for opencv 249 there is a BUILD_opencv_nonfree checkbox in CMake GUI

Answer (score 24, accepted):

with opencv3.0, SURF/SIFT and some other things have been moved  to a seperate [opencv_contrib repo](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/) .

you will have to download that, add it to your main opencv cmake settings (please look at the readme there), and rerun cmake/make.

then:

```
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"

...
Ptr<SIFT> sift = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(...);
sift->detect(...);
```

Comment: Thanks berak. I am following your suggested method. I have extracted the opencv_contrib-master in the opencv source folder. I am about to configure using Cmake(GUI), So I wanted to ask if there are any special flags in Cmake so that the build is built with the contrib modules?

Answer (score 0):

You could also install all the non-free stuff from this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ignaciovizzo/opencv3-nonfree
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```