# Opencv 3.0.0 installation with contrib-modules

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, build

I have a windows 8.1 PC on a 64 bit machine. I had already installed OpenCV 3.0.0 from source without opencv_contrib. Following the answer by berak-
[Nonfree module is missing in OpenCV 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418668/nonfree-module-is-missing-in-opencv-3-0/27419092#27419092), I downloaded the contrib and tried building opencv from source again but this time with OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES option turned on.

During this build process however, I got strange errors from the VS compiler. They were from the file

> \modules\line_descriptor\src\binary_descriptor.cpp

The errors were the following on line numbers as follows.

1. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='   E:\opencv\opencv-master\opencv_contrib-master\modules\line_descriptor\src\binary_descriptor.cpp line 833
2. error C2059: syntax error: '>' line 836
3. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'   E:\opencv\opencv-master\opencv_contrib-master\modules\line_descriptor\src\binary_descriptor.cpp line 837
4. error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\opencv_line_descriptor300d.lib' E:\opencv\opencv-master\build\modules\line_descriptor\LINK  opencv_test_line_descriptor
5. Error    7   error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
   if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
   :cmEnd
   endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
   :cmErrorLevel
   exit /b %1
   :cmDone
   if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
   :VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  132 5   INSTALL

Comment: well, the line_descriptor module does not build for me, either. try to disable it (cmake ... -DBUILD_opencv_line_descriptor=OFF) and rerun cmake

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it via the cmake-gui ?

Comment: Okay. Got it. Can you enlist other modules that don't work? So that I can avoid building those as well.

Comment: hmm, i'm on an outdated 32bit version, so our mileage may vary (as well as the *reasons* for something working or not). adas should be disabled (no module code there), cvv needs qt, saliency had probs here too, and i got no matlab..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem some weeks ago. i solved it this way:

edit the \modules\line_descriptor\src\binary_descriptor.cpp

and put this line after the defines:

```
#undef near
```

run cmake again (with -DBUILD_opencv_line_descriptor=ON)

what i disabled was: _cvv and _world