# OpenCV 3.0.0-beta missing KNN?

Tags: python-2.7, knn, opencv3.0

Having just upgraded from opencv-2.4.11, KNearest seems to be missing

```
In [27]: import cv2
In [28]: print(cv2.__version__)
3.0.0-beta

In [29]: cv2.KNearest()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d2ea29abad59> in <module>()
----> 1 cv2.KNearest()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KNearest'

In [30]: cv2.K
cv2.KAZE_DIFF_CHARBONNIER      cv2.KAZE_DIFF_WEICKERT         cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS      cv2.KeyPoint
cv2.KAZE_DIFF_PM_G1            cv2.KAZE_create                cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS  cv2.KeyPoint_convert
cv2.KAZE_DIFF_PM_G2            cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS          cv2.KalmanFilter               cv2.KeyPoint_overlap
```

Comment: A couple of others, too: SIFT, FastFeatureDetector, ORB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many modules were removed from OpenCV core and marked as nonfree. These modules have separate repository and has to be built separately.

The repository is here https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/

The info was found in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419092/892914

Answer (score 39):

In reality, `KNearest` has been moved to module `cv2.ml` in opencv3, and you have to call `cv2.ml.KNearest_create()` for using knn.

```
In [1]: import cv2

In [2]: cv2.__version__
Out[2]: '3.0.0'

In [3]: cv2.ml.KNea
cv2.ml.KNearest_BRUTE_FORCE  cv2.ml.KNearest_create   cv2.ml.KNearest_KDTREE

In [3]: cv2.ml.KNearest_create
```

For more details, please run `help(cv2.ml.KNearest_create())`.

Enjoy :)