# cv2.ml_KNearest object has no attribute find_nearest

Tags: python, opencv

I am a beginner in `openCV` and am trying to execute a given piece of code.I am using `Python 2.7` with `OpenCV3.0`.

The previous code was in an earlier version of `OpenCV` and so it had used `KNearest` which I modified as `cv2.ml.KNearest_create()` as suggested by this post [OpenCV 3.0.0-beta missing KNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369907/opencv-3-0-0-beta-missing-knn)

Now when I am trying to access the `findnearest` method, I am getting an error: `cv2.ml.knearest object has no attribute find_nearest`

Below is the code sample

```
model = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()

roi = dilate[by:by+bh,bx:bx+bw]
small_roi = cv2.resize(roi,(10,10))
feature = small_roi.reshape((1,100)).astype(np.float32)
ret,results,neigh,dist = model.find_nearest(feature,k=1)
```

Is there any change in the method name in `OpenCV3.0`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I replaced the find_nearest with findNearest and it worked like a charm.

So I believe findNearest is the version of find_nearest in OpenCV3.0.