# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm1'

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, opencv3.0, knn

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python pntc6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pntc6.py", line 24, in <module>
knn = cv2.m1.KNearest_create()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm1'
```

i am trying to follow the tutorial http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_knn/py_knn_opencv/py_knn_opencv.html and had this problem [OpenCV 3.0.0-beta missing KNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369907/opencv-3-0-0-beta-missing-knn) 
i tried to replace `KNearest` with `cv2.ml` and `cv2.ml` but all i get is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm1'`

(i am using a raspberry pi and followed this tutorial to install open cv http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/ subsequently i pip installed matplotlib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to replace KNearest with cv2.ml and cv2.ml but all i get is AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm1'

```
knn = cv2.m1.KNearest_create()
           ^
           |__ this needs to be ml, not m1
```

But your code suggests you typed `m1` (M and number 1), not `ml` (letters M and L, as in Machine Learning)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful.