# errors while compiling nonfree/features2d.hpp

Tags: opencv, opencv-features2d

I am trying to write a `c++` program using the `SIFT`. I have already installed and built the `opencv_contrib-master` module as some have suggested that the latest version of `OpenCV` (version 3.0 which i have) doesn't have this module. I can physically locate the nonfree folder as well as the featuures2d file in it but every time i try to compile, i get the following errors inside of the '`features2d.hpp`' file itself:

```
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:73: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:73: error: 'vector' has not been declared
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:77: error: 'vector' has not been declared vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:77: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:83: error: 'vector' has not been declared void buildGaussianPyramid( const Mat& base, vector<Mat>& pyr, int nOctaves ) const; vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:76: error: 'void cv::SIFT::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const' cannot be overloaded void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:72: error: with 'void cv::SIFT::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const'
 void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,  vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
```

There are a total of 26 errors but most of them are the '`vector not declared`' type although i have included `vector.h` as well. The main program recognizes siftfeaturedetector but the errors are all coming from the `nonfree/features2d.hpp` file. Any suggestions what might be wrong here?
 I'm also very new to `OpenCV` and apologize for my lack of technical details.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nonfree module is missing in OpenCV 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418668/nonfree-module-is-missing-in-opencv-3-0)