# error /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp error vector in opencv on ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, opencv, surf

This code is surf algorithm of Opencv. My code is not working. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 with Opencv 3.0.0 and gcc/g++ 4.8.4. I want to complie on "surf algorithm"

ERROR content

> /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:73:21: error:
>                                            ‘vector’ has not been declared
>                        vector& keypoints) const;
>                        ^
>
> /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:73:27: error:
>                                       expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
>                        vector& keypoints) const;
>                              ^
>
> /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:77:21: error:
>                                       ‘vector’ has not been declared
>                        vector& keypoints,
>                        ^
>
> /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:77:27: error:
>                                       expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
>                        vector& keypoints,

'test_surf.cpp'

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 if( argc != 3)
 {
 cout <<" Usage: sift input_image output_image" << endl;
 return -1;
 }

 //cv::initModule_nonfree();
 //cout <<"initModule_nonfree() called" << endl;

 Mat image;
 image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
 if(! image.data )
 {
 cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
 return -1;
 }

 vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
 Mat descriptors;

 // Create a SIFT keypoint detector.
 SiftFeatureDetector detector;
 detector.detect(image, keypoints);
 cout << "Detected " << (int) keypoints.size() << " keypoints" <<endl;

 // Compute feature description.
 detector.compute(image,keypoints, descriptors);
 cout << "Computed feature."<<endl;

 // Store description to "descriptors.des".
 FileStorage fs;
 fs.open("descriptors.des", FileStorage::WRITE);
 cout << "Opened file to store the features."<<endl;
 fs << "descriptors" << descriptors;
 cout << "Finished writing file."<<endl;
 fs.release();
 cout << "Released file."<<endl;

 // Show keypoints in the output image.
 Mat outputImg;
 Scalar keypointColor = Scalar(255, 0, 0);
 drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, outputImg, keypointColor, DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
 cout << "Drew keypoints in output image file."<<endl;
//
#ifdef WIN32
 namedWindow("Output image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow("Output image", outputImg);
 waitKey(0);
#endif

 cout << "Generate the output image."<<endl;
 imwrite(argv[2], outputImg);

 cout << "Done."<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to include header <vector>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nonfree module is missing in OpenCV 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418668/nonfree-module-is-missing-in-opencv-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include header file vector

```
  #include <vector>
```

refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/