# Error In OpenCv

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, opencv3.0

I installed opencv and configure it from tutorials, but when I am trying a code implementing it, all what is related to opencv is shown as an error as shown in the figure. Can you please help me? I really need it
[image]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    
using namespace cv;

int Main( void)
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;

    // Start Capture From WebCam
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
    if( !capture )
    {
        cout << "No camera Detected" << endl;
    }
    // Create New Window
    cvNamedWindow( "My OpenCV WebCam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    if( capture )
    {
        cout << "WebCam Is In capture" << endl;
        for(;;)
        {
            // Get Captured Image And Show It In The New Window 
            // You Can Do Save It Or Filter It
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );

            // Use This To Filter Image
            //cvNot(iplImg, iplImg);

            cvShowImage( "My OpenCV WebCam", iplImg );

            if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                break;
        } 
    } 


    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "My OpenCV WebCam" );

    return 0;

}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) OpenCV version? 2) include and library directories? 3) additional libraris? 4) Why are you still using `IplImage` and old C syntax? Use C++ syntax

Comment: ...and remove  #include "stdafx.h"

Comment: opencv 3.0.0, Visual studio 2012.. and yes I included libraries

Comment: This was an online code I just test it

Comment: can you show you configurations 2) and 3) ?

Comment: test with [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) code

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/2dqu62a.png

Comment: why you're linking OpenCV 2.4.8 when you said you're using OpenCV 3.0?

Comment: It gives error also with the code you gave it to me.. the problem is in the configuration of opencv not in codes

Comment: I did not notice that I just watched a video and do like it.. so I have to change libraries of 248 to those of 300 in the linking?

Comment: yes, and change accordingly also library directory

Comment: okk Thank you very much :) You really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments to the question it turned out that the OP was linking to OpenCV 2.4.8, instead of OpenCV 3.0.0.

Correcting the linked libraries name, as well as the library path, solved the issue.

Comment: I just correct them .. But I have one more question plz.. The code I have to test has imports like this : 
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
How can I deal with them for opencv3? Since those who give an error now

Comment: @user3552658 be sure that the inlcude directory is <OPENCV_DIR>/build/include

Comment: it won't work for `nonfree`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418668/nonfree-module-is-missing-in-opencv-3-0)

Comment: Miki can you help me here plz 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387227/the-program-has-exited-with-code-1-0xffffffff