# program of SURF in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am working with OpenCV on an Ubuntu machine. 
I could not compile a program using SURF. This is the code :

```
CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);
cvExtractSURF( image, 0, &imageKeypoints, &imageDescriptors, storage, params );
for( i = 0; i < imageKeypoints->total; i++ )
    {
CvSURFPoint* r = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( imageKeypoints, i );
CvPoint center;
int radius;
center.x = cvRound(r->pt.x);
center.y = cvRound(r->pt.y);
radius = cvRound(r->size*1.2/9.*2);
cvCircle( frame, center, radius, red_color[0], 1, 8, 0 );
```

The program doesn't recognize all of the above functions even if openCV is installed.

```
 error: ‘CvSURFParams’ was not declared in this scope
CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘params’
 CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);
```

error: ‘params’ was not declared in this scope
       cvExtractSURF( image, 0, &imageKeypoints, &imageDescriptors, storage,  params );
Thanks

Younès

Comment: Please don't use obsolete C syntax! If you're using OpenCV 3 those functions are gone!

Comment: this legacy code was removed a long time ago, don't waste any further time on that. for opencv3, [have a look here](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html)

Comment: Where could I find the header #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"?  I am working on Ubuntu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27418668/5008845