# fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, fatal-error

I am trying to build this code:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with CLion 2017.3 and have OpenCV 3.4 installed.

xfeatures2d.hpp can't be found on the system.

I have looked at many different problems on the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

Any help?

Comment: non-free libs need to be explicitly downloaded, did you do this? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418668/nonfree-module-is-missing-in-opencv-3-0  the repository is here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't don this. I will try it right away...

Comment: All the non-free (patent protected stuff) and experimental libs are separate downloads from the main package so they have to be downloaded separately I think this change was made between openCV 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You have to include cmake comiplation flag to opencv OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH and set it to the opencv_contrib/modules.
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do to compile OpenCV with xfeatures2d:

- Download [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) (I took a release from the [releases page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tags)). This step is what gives us xfeatures2d.
- Unpack the tarball somewhere, e.g., `~/src/opencv_contrib-4.5.5`
- When configuring OpenCV (the main OpenCV source like `opencv-4.5.2`) with CMake, add the following option to cmake command line (adjusting the value to be your actual path to the `modules` subdirectory of the `opencv_contrib` tarball):

```
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME/src/opencv_contrib-4.5.5/modules/
```

- Now just build as you normally would and install.

The above actions gave me the expected file (among others): `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp`.